# If not exist with Date SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

i want to add the time, if there is free time as example
im doing that with two textboxes where im entering the date

Database
20.04.2020 - 20.05.2020

so there should be no possibility to add a time, i guess? as example

16.04.2020 - 16.04.2020 or
22.04.2020 . 18.05.2020

my code right now is

```
If not exists (Select * From Praktikum where P_Start >= '" + tbZeit.Text + "' and P_Ende <= '" + tbZeit1.Text + "' ) Begin INSERT INTO Praktikum (P_Start, P_Ende ) VALUES ( '" + tbZeit.Text + "', '" + tbZeit1.Text + "' )End";
```

Outcome would be with tb1 16.04.2014 and tb2 16.06.2014

```
If not exists (Select * From Praktikum where P_Start >= '16.04.2014' and P_Ende < '16.06.2014' ) Begin INSERT INTO Praktikum (P_Start, P_Ende) VALUES ('16.04.2014', '16.06.2014') End
```

Comment: Pleas add table definition for Praktikum

Comment: Primary Key P_Start - date
                    P_Ende - date

Comment: Mysql date datatypes are stored in the form yyyy-dd-mm for comparison purposes you need to pass a date in this format. And times is stored in the format hh:mm:ss. Your question is unclear but you should research mysql date datatypes

Comment: My dates are stored correctly, my only issue is the sorting with if not exists
like if the date is before the beginning time and after, it still get stored

Answer (score 0):

Please use the date conversion to specific format for the date value and check

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is tests to reject where input from and to dates fall between existing dates or span them for example

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t
(id int auto_increment primary key, from_dt date,to_dt date);

insert into t (from_dt,to_dt) values ('20.04.2020' , '20.05.2020');



select * from t;
set @from = '2020-04-20';
set @to   = '2020-05-20';

delete from t where id > 1;

insert into t (from_dt,to_dt)
select @from,@to
where not exists
(select 1
from t 
where @from between from_dt and to_dt or
      @to   between from_dt and to_dt or
      (from_dt between @from and @end) or
      (to_dt between @from and @end) or
      (@from < from_dt and @to > to_dt)
);

select * from t;
```

And here's a place for you to play https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=597e9c3f22518252eb1415ec7ce407e1